# How to make a ConfigurationProperty of type String returns null when not present in the config file

Tags: .net, configuration

I have a custom configuration that I built and one of the properties (actually, some of them) are strings. I need them to be null if the user has not set them in the app.config, but it seems that .NET's configuration system insists on returning `string.Empty` in those cases.

I can, of course, check for a string.Empty and return null on those cases, but that's error-prone and most likely won't handle all cases (such as when I can have both a null and an empty string).

Answer (score 0):

Just so I understand, do you need to treat `null` the same as `string.empty` or different?

If you want to treat them both the same you can always use `string.isnullorempty()`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I treat them differently.